# Inter-Planetary Communication

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, space, communication, solar-system

In my universe humans have colonized Phobos, Deimos, the moon, and Mars. However, they have no fast way to communicate with each other. I'm looking for a fast and possible way for humans to communicate within the solar system.

Comment: How fast is "fast"? 40 months? 40 minutes? 0.4 seconds?

Comment: Three problems. First off, your post is too vague; I would suggest that you add more information about what you are looking for. For example: I would like it to be instantaneous.  Second, you grammar is atrocious. This is not necessarily a "huge" problem; lots of posts on this site have less-than-optimal grammar, its just that bad grammar makes your question really hard to read.  Finally, your username is really offensive to me as a Christian; could you please change it to something less offensive?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  I see you've already chosen as answer as "best" -- it's considered very bad form to do this within two or three days of posting a query. Give it some time to see what kinds of answers you get.  Also, it seems like your query is heading for closure due to being unclear. ("How fast is fast?") Please review the [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how to write good questions here!

Comment: @thescribe-ReinstateMonica at least for the second problem - feel free to [edit] the question to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easiest and simplest route of communication is radio**

Barring that, any form of fluctuation / pattern in the EM spectrum (which includes radio, but also other wavelengths of light such as microwaves). Communication via this means is a simple rod with a current running through it, picked up by an antenna being another rod that you could measure current fluctuations within.

If this is somehow prevented then I would question your colony's technical ability and their ability to be on those planets / moons. If they do practice Technoprimitivism, we can look at older forms of communication.

Perhaps then a simple telescope and mirror system - bouncing sunlight off mirrors towards your receiver in coded message to be then observed by a telescope on another planetary body. Your mirrors need to be enormous and distributed to be able to be observed, and constantly monitored.

Or preventing this - a inter-planetary 'mailing' system, with small rockets being launched to make deliveries of ultra-small payloads. This is ultra-expensive and there is no way to slow down the payload on delivery to the moons - so they simply 'crash'. To prevent damage, perhaps the message is encoded in a protected capsule.

Answer (score -2):

Quantum entanglement.

Assuming radio is not good enough for these impatient people, quantum entanglement is a fun idea.  Two quantum particles that are created together become entangled, and any change in spin to one of them changes the spin in the other, instantaneously, at any distance across the universe.  This has been real world tested even across two islands.  Infinitely faster than radio.

Course, as any physicist will tell you, relativity doesn't give up that easily and there are certain real world reasons why this is impossible under our current understanding (the particles may be able to effect each other faster than light, but our information about them still only moves at the speed of light, it's messy).

But if you make certain assumptions about finding a way past that limitation with future tech, it is fun to think that the colonies may need to rely on regular but limited shipments of entangled particles for communications.  Or if they are cut off, only have the previous few their ancestors brought.

BUTTTTT, if you need something that would work now, and is esoteric, consider mirrors and lasers.  Apollo missions left a mirror on the moon which we point a laser at to determine if its distance is changing.  Giant lasers and telescopes could work as a kind of morse code between planets, calibrated with mirrors.

Comment: [Entanglement doesn't transfer information](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/169962/56299) at all, let alone at high speeds. Whatever method you used to transmit information, it wouldn't have anything to do with quantum entanglement. I'm a little confused as to why you mention it. . .

Comment: *"Left a mirror on the Moon":* There are five retroreflectors on the Moon, three American (placed by Apollo 11, 14, and 15) and two Franco-Soviet (placed by Luna 17 and 21; the mirrors are French-built, the spacecraft and the rovers were Soviet-built).

Comment: @HDE226868, though the physics forum would be better equipped to discuss the finer details of quantum mechanics (and the members there better than I at talking about it), I find this article on quantum communication methods to be a good introduction: https://singularityhub.com/2018/12/26/quantum-communication-just-took-a-great-leap-forward/ .  AlexP, thanks for that added info, I think I would like to learn more about the topic.